# Form Table out of JSON Array

Tags: php, json

I've got a simple question.

I'm getting a PHP Array from a mysql query and I encoded it so it looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "ID": "111111",
        "JoinDate": "2015-05-13",
        "Nickname": "TestUser1"
    },
    {
        "ID": "222222",
        "JoinDate": "2015-05-06",
        "Nickname": "TestUser2"
    },
    {
        "ID": "333333",
        "JoinDate": "2000-01-01",
        "Nickname": "TestUser3"
    }
]
```

How can I iterate through this Array and Form a simple HTML Table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heres an example of outputting array elements in table rows.

```
foreach ($elements as $element) {
   echo '<tr><td>'. $element['ID'].'</td><td>>'. $element['Nickname'].'</td></tr>';
}
```